Add divider with full height in Jetpack Compose
I'm trying to add a divider in a table of dynamic data where each items can have long strings too but divider is not covering full height as per the values.
Row {
    for (columnNumber in columnInfo.indices) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentHeight()
                .background(Color.White),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        ) {
            Row(
                Modifier
                    .height(IntrinsicSize.Min)
                    .wrapContentWidth()
                    .background(Color.White),
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = cellViewModel(columnNumber, rowNumber).formattedDisplayText,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .width(columnInfo[columnNumber].width)
                        .padding(top = 2.dp, bottom = 1.dp, start = 10.dp),
                    fontFamily = fonts,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                    color = Color.Black
                )

                Divider(
                    color = Color.Red,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxHeight()
                        .width(1.dp)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

But it shows like

Can you guide how I can have divider as full height?

Why don't you use a vertical grid instead?

The problem is your column structure. You are creating columns, then rows parented to each column. Each individual cell therefore becomes an individual row, and the divider that comes after has no idea about the size of other cells.
You'll need to have all of the elements in the same row have the same Row element as a parent in order for the intrinsic measurements to be correctly calculated.
See also: Intrinsic measurements in Compose layouts

I tried that also but it didn't work.

What did you try specifically?

Try calculating height of full Row and set height of full Row as Divider Height
Here is example Code:
    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .wrapContentWidth()
        .padding(padding)) {

        val density = LocalDensity.current
        var rowHeight by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(10f) }
        Row(modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.White)
            .drawBehind {
                rowHeight = size.height // calculate Height of row set
            }) {
            for (i in 0 until 4) {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .background(Color.White),
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                ) {
                    Row(
                        Modifier
                            .height(IntrinsicSize.Min)
                            .wrapContentWidth()
                            .background(Color.White),
                        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                    ) {
                        Text(
                            text = if (i == 3) "Line1\nLine2\nLine3" else "Text$i",
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .width(80.dp)
                                .padding(top = 2.dp, bottom = 1.dp, start = 10.dp),
                            textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                            color = Color.Black
                        )
                        VerticalDivider(
                            color = Color.Red,
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .height(density.run { rowHeight.toDp() }) // set row height as Divider Height
                                .width(1.dp)
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

You will get output like following image

I hope it helps
